# Updating UWP binding programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, uwp

I've got an issue where if an item is selected in a list I want it to update my items in my grid. The binding is done by:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
                <ItemsControl x:Name="RightGridItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding News}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RightGridTemplate}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When an item, e.g. Planet is selected, I want to update the ItemsSource binding to a new list. This is specified in my DataModel.

How can I update this programmatically? I've tried something like this, but it requires a `DependencyObject` and can't find out what it means. This also looks like WPF rather than UWP.

```
`var myBinding = new Binding
                    {
                        Source = Planets,
                        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                    };
                    BindingOperations.SetBinding(new , ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);`
```

What should I put as the first item for the contstructor for `'SetBinding'`?

Comment: First parameter should be `RightGridItemsControl`, and don't forget set `Path` property in `Binding` class.

Comment: How do I get a reference in my viewmodel of `RightGridItemsControl` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the Binding like this:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(
    RightGridItemsControl, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

or like this:

```
RightGridItemsControl.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

Note also that currently there is no property path present in your Binding. If there is a `News` property as in your XAML, the Binding should probably look like shown below, without `Mode = BindingMode.OneWay`, which is the default, and without `UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged`, which has no effect in a one-way binding.

```
var myBinding = new Binding
{
    Source = Planets,
    Path = new PropertyPath("News")
};
```

Comment: How can I reference `RightGridItemsControl` ? It's only set as a string in the XAML and I don't have any intellisense.

Comment: I'm using a viewmodel as well, not the code behind.

Comment: `x:Name="RightGridItemsControl" ` creates a field in the XAML's class.